# Make program sleep until a windows task has completed

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a small program that will backup some important files then uninstall a program. once that is done it will then install a bunch of new stuff and backup the old files and configure everything. It works fine but the problem is when i run the program it just loads up a bunch of installers and restores the backup files before the programs have even installed.

I know this is happening because the java isnt responsible for the install of the programs its windows job but is there a way to delay the program so that it wont go onto the next step until the last 1 has completed? i could guess roughly how long it takes to complete a step and use thread.sleep() but i would like something more accurate. Is there a way to somehow find out from windows when it has finished doing a task?

Comment: do you control the installed programs? the code e.g.? if not, do they leave values on the registry?

Comment: the programs are installed and uninstalled by windows eg a program like firefox so yes they will contain a registry value. would a while(<registryvalue>.exists){do nothing} work? because i have a lot of registry entries for programs that no longer exist on my pc

Comment: registry should have a list of installed programs actually... even the file paths and file existence could be useful .. like while <file>!exist...

Comment: does your Java program start Windows the intallers or do you start the installers externally?

Comment: the installers are started through the windows command line. the java code will open cmd insert the command then close it. this then loads up the uninstaller. so the java code will never know when the install is finished because it isnt in control of them but i was thinking there might be some sort of message output by windows on completion that the code could listen for

Answer (score 2):

If you start the installer using the `ProcessBuilder` then you get a `Process` object returned when you call `start()`.

If you then call [`waitfor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) on the `Process` your thread will wait until the installer is finished.

Comment: the process builder wont load an uninstaller that uses MsiExec.exe since the value for it that the registry returns is always null. since it requries the command line to run the processbuilder wont do it